# Artificially duplicate results in mysql

Tags: mysql, date, join

I have a table like so

```
+---------+
| weekday |
+---------+
|    2    |
|    5    |
|    3    |
+---------+
```

Now I want to have a resultset in which I see the dates of this and the upcoming week like so:

```
+------------+---------+
|    date    | weekday |
+------------+---------+
| 2019-12-18 |    2    |
| 2019-12-21 |    5    |
| 2019-12-19 |    3    |
| 2019-12-25 |    2    |
| 2019-12-28 |    5    |
| 2019-12-26 |    3    |
+------------+---------+
```

So far I have this query

```sql
SELECT 
    CURDATE() + INTERVAL w.weekday - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY AS thisWeek,
    CURDATE() + INTERVAL w.weekday + 7 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY AS nextWeek,
    dw.weekday
FROM
    weekdays AS w
```

Which gives me this result

```
+------------+------------+---------+
|  thisWeek  |  nextWeek  | weekday |
+------------+------------+---------+
| 2019-12-18 | 2019-12-25 |    2    |
| 2019-12-21 | 2019-12-28 |    5    |
| 2019-12-19 | 2019-12-26 |    3    |
+------------+------------+---------+
```

How would I have to need to proceed to get the former resultset?

Comment: Feel free to edit the question-titel as I didnt knew how to articulate it better.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT 
    CURDATE() + INTERVAL w.weekday - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY AS date
    dw.weekday
FROM
    weekdays AS w
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    CURDATE() + INTERVAL w.weekday + 7 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY AS date
    dw.weekday
FROM
    weekdays AS w;
```

Comment: Would it be possible to achieve a similar result with a `JOIN`?

Comment: Maybe with a full join and `coalesce()`. But a join isn't the ideal too here I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using UNION

```
select  thisWeek date, weekday
from  (

  SELECT 
      CURDATE() + INTERVAL w.weekday - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY AS thisWeek,
      CURDATE() + INTERVAL w.weekday + 7 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY AS nextWeek,
      dw.weekday
  FROM   weekdays AS w

) t1 
union all  
select  nextWeek date, weekday 
from  (

  SELECT 
      CURDATE() + INTERVAL w.weekday - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY AS thisWeek,
      CURDATE() + INTERVAL w.weekday + 7 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY AS nextWeek,
      dw.weekday
  FROM   weekdays AS w
) t2
```

or for avoid subquery you could create a view

```
create view my_view as  
SELECT 
      CURDATE() + INTERVAL w.weekday - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY AS thisWeek,
      CURDATE() + INTERVAL w.weekday + 7 - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY AS nextWeek,
      dw.weekday
  FROM   weekdays
```

then the query  is

```
select  thisWeek date, weekday
from my_view 
union all  
select  nextWeek date, weekday 
from  my_view
```

Comment: Would it be possible to achieve a similar result with a `JOIN`?

Comment: Why a JOIN    .. should be more expensive for performance  ..  in this case the UNION is the best way ..

Comment: because otherwise i have to write the subselect twice.

Comment: You can create a view and use the view  ..  instead of the subquery

Comment: i would have to pass a parameter to it since both subqueries wouldnt be similiar, i.e. `thisWeek` and `nextWeek` would be `date` depending on the parameter